# Insertion sort on small arrays with merge procedure:

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge

Consider the problem:

Although merge sort runs in `Θ(nlgn)` worst-case time and insertion sort runs in `Θ(n^2)` worstcase
time, the constant factors in insertion sort makes it faster for small `n`. Thus, it makes sense to use insertion sort within merge sort when subproblems become sufficiently small.
Consider a modification for merge sort in which `n/k` sublists of length `k` are sorted using insertion sort and then merged using the standard merging mechanism, where `k` is a value to be determined.

**Question:** Show that the sublists can be merged in `Θ(n lg(n/k))` worst-case time:

**My solution:**

To merge `n/k` sublists into `n/2k` it takes `Θ(n)` times

To merge `n/2k` sublists into `n/4k` it takes `Θ(n)` times

...

To merge 2 sublists into 1 it takes `Θ(n)` times

Then I was struggling with further steps and I had a look at the solution:

We have ***`lg(n/k)` such merges***, so merging `n/k` sublists into one list takes `Θ(n lg(n/k))` worst-case time.

I have two questions:

1)How do they end up with ***`lg(n/k)` merges***? Please, clarify the calculations?

2)Why is the final result ***`Θ(n lg(n/k))`***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be pretty close to the actual answer. I believe the phrasing of the answer you looked up is what makes it harder for you to understand, because I do not think that the total number of individual merges required is `lg(n/k)`. What I believe the answer refers to is the number of merging *steps* required until we end up with the sorted list.

Instead of the answer, however, let's continue building onto your reasoning. Merging two lists of length `k` has `O(k)` time complexity. To merge `n/k` such lists into `n/(2k)` lists, we will do `n/(2k)` merges with complexity `O(k)` each, resulting in an overall `O(n)` complexity, as you mentioned.

You may extend this logic to the next *step*, where `n/(2k)` lists are merged into `n/(4k)`, and state that the second step has `O(n)` complexity, as well. In fact, each merging *step*, will take `O(n)` time.

The next thing to do here is estimating how many of these merging *steps* we have. We started with `n/k` lists, and after the first step we obtained `n/(2k)` lists. After that, at each step, the number of lists is halved, until there is only 1 list left, which will be our result. (i.e. sorted list) Well, how many times do you think we have to divide `n/k` by 2, until we end up with 1? That is exactly what `log(n/k)` means, isn't it? So, there will be `log(n/k)` of such merging steps, each of which takes `O(n)`.

Consequently, the entire procedure will have a time complexity of `O(nlog(n/k))`.